Prove the convergence for a sequence of functions
My book is presenting sequence of functions, and gives the following exercise:
For each natural $n$, $n \ge 1$, let $f_n$ given by
$f_n(x)= \begin{cases} 
2n^2x & 0 \le x \le \frac{1}{2n} \\
-2n^2x+2n & \frac{1}{2n} < x \le \frac{1}{n} \\
0 & \frac{1}{n} < x \le 1
\end{cases}$
Show that, for all $x \in [0,1]$, $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)=0$.
I've tried to tackle the case $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{2n}$, as follows:
Supposing that $f_n$ converges to zero, we have to show that, given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$n>n_0 \implies |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$
But  we have
$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|2n^2x-0|=|2n^2x|=2n^2x \le 2n^2*\frac{1}{2n}=n \implies |f_n(x)-f(x)| \le n$
Now, how do I relate $n$ and $\epsilon$ to have $|f_n(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon$?
Thanks for any help.

Actually, you don't need to consider the case $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{2n}$ and the case $\frac{1}{2n} \le x \le \frac{1}{n}$ since for any $x \in [0, 1]$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N} \lt x$. Indeed, by Archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$, we can take $N$ satisfying $\frac{1}{x} \lt N$.
Then, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \ge N$, since $\frac{1}{n} \lt x$, $f_n(x)=0$. It implies $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)=0 \quad \forall x \in [0, 1]$.

EDIT: The above argument only works for any $x \in (0,1]$ since $\frac{1}{x}$ does not exists when $x=0$. If $x=0$,
$$f_n(0) = 2n^2 \cdot 0 = 0 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$
Hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)=0$.

But how we conclude that $\frac{1}{n}<x \implies f_n(x)=0$ ?

You assume $f_n(x)=0$ if $\frac{1}{n} \lt x$. Therefore, if we take arbitrary $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\epsilon \gt 0$ and arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n \ge N$,
$$|f_n(x)| = 0 \lt \epsilon$$
In general, if for the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ there exist $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$x_n=x \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \quad s.t. \quad n \ge N$$
then we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x$. It can be shown by the definition of the convergence of sequences.
